# Kernel density estimation to check whether distribution is lognormal

Tags: self-study, stata, normality-assumption, kernel-smoothing

I am using the kdens package in Stata to estimate the kernel density of some economic data. I would like to check if my data could possibly come from a normal distribution. My question is about the selection of bandwidth in kernel density estimation. I know that if I choose a bandwidth sufficiently below the optimal bandwidth, I get zero bias asymptotically. So then I could simply construct my confidence intervals for the density estimate and see if the normal density lies within the interval. The figure below shows the results for this.

[image]

However, if I choose a larger bandwidth (oversmoothing), then I get the following result.

[image]

My final conclusion (normality) would be different for two different bandwidths. I would appreciate it if someone could explain me how to proceed from here on.

Comment: Kernel density estimation is not how I would assess normality. Use a normal probability plot (`qnorm` in Stata). Your plots hint at strong granularity in the data (spikes at certain values) which makes any claim to normality both less plausible and more difficult to test.

Comment: As your variable appears to be in logarithm form already, you are checking for a lognormal distribution.

Comment: @NickCox Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I have to use the kernel density estimation method to assess normality. You are right about the lognormal part.

Comment: I don't understand the "have to". If this is homework or more generally self-study it should be flagged and tagged as such. Note that your kernel shape (Epanechnikov default)  is all too visible in the graphs, emblematic of spikes in the data.